# what does || (Parallel sign) mean in DB2 Sql?

Tags: db2

What does `||` mean in this db2 syntax?

[image]

Comment: The `||` is the concatenation operator in SQL

Answer (score 3):

The `||` is shorthand for `CONCAT`.

Comment: It's probably the other way around. `CONCAT()` is a function that does the same thing as the concatenation operator `||` and can accept multiple parameters. `CONCAT` is not even a reserved word in standard SQL.

Comment: Amusingly enough, it really is that || is [short-hand for CONCAT in DB2](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000736.html) but then DB2 (and Oracle) both pre-date the SQL standard so I could believe they picked something excessively verbose for concatenation at first (especially given SQL's general tendency toward verbal excess)